# Using boost::ref to indicate intention in coding conventions

Tags: c++, boost, coding-style, conventions, ref

When functions take non-const refs as arguments, it can create hard-to-read code because at the calling site it is not obvious which inputs might be changed. This has lead some code conventions to enforce that pointers be used instead, for example

```
void func(int input, int* output);

int input = 1, output = 0;
func(input, &output);
```

instead of

```
void func(int input, int& output);

int input = 1, output = 0;
func(input, output);
```

Personally, I hate using pointers because of the need to check for null. This has lead me to wonder if boost::ref (or std::ref for C++11) can be used to signal intention, as follows:

```
void func(int input, int& output);

int input = 1, output = 0;
func(input, boost::ref(output));
```

This would be used as a company coding convention. **My question is, are there any reasons why this would not be a good idea?**

Comment: I don't really buy into avoiding non-const references because you need to look at the declaration of the function anyways to make sure you're calling it right (correct number of params, correct types.) I don't see any reasons why your idea is a bad idea, I just don't think it gains you that much in the long run.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a bad idea, but it's not really enforced (as PiotrNycz notes). It's effectively just a comment.

We can do better though:

```
template <typename T>
class output_argument
{
public:
    template <typename U>
    friend output_argument<U> out(U& ref);

    T& get() const
    {
        return mRef;
    }

    operator T&() const
    {
        return get();
    }

private:
    explicit output_argument(T& ref) :
    mRef(ref)
    {}

    output_argument& operator=(const output_argument&); // not defined

    T& mRef;
};

template <typename U>
output_argument<U> out(U& ref)
{
    return output_argument<U>(ref);
}
```

Giving:

```
void foo(int x, output_argument<float> f)
{
    int i = static_cast<int>(f);

    f.get() = static_cast<float>(i + x);
}

int main()
{
    float f = 5.0f;

    //fails: foo(1, f);
    foo(1, out(f));
}
```

But generally these kinds of utilities are not necessary, because the function name should convey what's happening to the arguments: `swap(x, y)` quite clearly modifies the arguments! And returning values should be done with a return type, further limiting the cases this utility can be used.

Comment: Furthermore, with move semantics, you do not have pay the performance penalty for the copy when returning the value.  Thus, the typical pattern for using an out-parameter should be rare.

Answer (score 1):

This company coding convention could be easily (by mistake of course) broken like this:

```
void func(int input, int& output);

int input = 1, output = 0;
func(boost::ref(input), output);
```

this compiles and works fine - but is misleading to readers.

Better would be to let func be of good name, suggesting that some arguments are modified in it:

```
void copyTo(int input, int& output);
```

In modern IDE - you can see while reading what the function is doing.

---

Maybe better company coding convention would in opposite way, by using boost::cref:

```
void func(int input, int& output);

int input = 1, output = 0;
func(boost::cref(input), output);
```

Here mistakes like with boost::ref is not possible...